# Intelab smpp client library

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, smpp

I am new to SMPP protocol and using c#,.net but manage to connect with server and when I try to send SMS I failed again and again because the rules of SMS sending process in India. I have to pass the additional parameters but I am not able to do this. Please help me to resolve this issue. As the documents said "Ref to new TLV Parameter in SMPP document, you need to send the PE ID & TEMPLATE ID  under the Two Optional  Tag Value HEX  1400 & 1401.

PE ID will be under optional Tag Value - 1400 & TEMPLATE ID will be under optional  Tag Value – 1401."

C# , smpp server

Seeking help to resolve my issue of smpp server in India